# Center text in ul with floated li's

Tags: html, css, width, parent-child, html-lists

I have a UL who's LIs are floated right. I would like to center align the text in the UL, but I see that if I don't specify the UL's width, it thinks that it's 100%, and doesn't center align the LIs.
However, I cannot give the UL a specific width because the data in the LIs is dynamic.
Also, because the UL's width is 100%, it doesn't help to wrap the UL in a DIV and give the DIV a rule of text-align:center.
Is there a CSS only way to get the UL to center it's LIs?
A demo page with the said LI is [here](http://clickit3.ort.org.il/APPS/WW/Page.aspx?ws=c6545e4a-18ea-4908-a698-8ed6c5a269fd&page=583fe1b3-ef6e-45c2-944d-1281bb81b7f4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [very simple solution](https://web.archive.org/web/20111029151406/http://www.markrushworth.com/css-center-unordered-list-ulli-based-menu/), that works for me in both FF and in IE:

CSS:

```
#footer{text-align:center;list-style:none}
#footer li{display:inline}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id=”footer”>
<li><a href=”1.asp”>Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href=”2n.asp”>Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href=”3.asp”>Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Page ends in error 404 - Would be great if you add the actual solution :)

Answer (score 2):

If you need dynamic explicit widths for the lis you can use inline-block.

```
#list { text-align:center; }
#list li { display:inline-block; }
```

You'll have to [work around for IE](http://work.arounds.org/issue/18/using-inline-block-ie7-and-ie6/).